# How do I convert an IP address to binary representation in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with a list of IP addresses in dotted decimal form. How do I convert these IP addresses to binary representation using Excel?

Answer (score 2):

With O365's newer functions this is straightforward:

`=CONCAT(DEC2BIN(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"."),8))`

Answer (score 1):

Following Excel formula convert a given IP address in a excel cell to its binary form.

[image]

In following example, the IP address is located in the cell A17. That is the only value you need to modify to use this in your excel sheet.

```
=CONCATENATE(DEC2BIN(LEFT(A17,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",1))-1),8),DEC2BIN(MID(A17,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",1))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",2))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",1))-1),8),DEC2BIN(MID(A17,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",2))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",3))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",2))-1),8),DEC2BIN(RIGHT(A17,LEN(A17)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A17,".","~",3))),8))
```

DEC2BIN(CELL, 8) convert the number in the cell to binary format and keep leading 0s.
SUBSTITUTE function is used here as FIND does not allow finding the Nth occurrence of a character.
SUBSTITUTE function helps to replace Nth occurrence of the character with a character not in the text, allowing us to use the FIND character to get the location of the Nth character.

Answer (score 0):

Type "=DEC" without quotes in an Excel cell. ...
Click "DEC2BIN," the first of the three options. ...
Enter the number you wish to convert. ...
Type a comma.
Enter the number of bits you wish your binary number to contain. ...
Press "Enter." The binary number will appear.